# Django + Eclipse, shell issues

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I'm using pydev to use Django in Eclipse.  I'm following the tutorial here (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), making a simple poll application.  In the example when they run the shell they are able to do this:

```
from polls.models import Poll, Choice
```

however, for some reason, I'm not able to do this.  In order for it to work, I have to do this:

```
from projectname.polls.models import Poll, Choice
```

Any idea why that is?  Is it an eclipse thing?  Is some path wrong somewhere in my settings.py?  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'not able to do this'? Does it give an error or what?

Comment: eclipse autocompletes for me, but it won't autocomplete this.  If I try to do it anyway it says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named polls.models

Comment: From which directory are you accessing the project? Are you running the shell from your "projectname" directory?  Does it works when you use normal shell?

Comment: In eclipse, I right click on my project, click on django, then shell with django environment.  I'm not sure what directory it's running from.  Is there a command to tell?

Comment: I think the problem is that in Eclipse, you make a project and then the first folder it creates in that project is the name of your project, which is redundant...I don't know how to change that though

Comment: Have you properly followed the steps for configuring the Python interpreter in Eclipse?

Comment: Perhaps not.  Which steps are you referring to?

Comment: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html

Comment: I followed the directions there, but it looks like it has to do the same thing, "projectname.appname", in the shell

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that you're using PyDev. See how your PYTHONPATH is structured...

(right click on your project in package explorer > properties > Pydev - PYTHONPATH.

If your project is set up as

```
project_root/
+-projectname/
  +-polls/
    +-models.py
```

and if your PYTHONPATH points to `project_root`, then you'll have to refer to Poll class as `projectname.polls.models.Poll`. However, if you set the PYTHONPATH to `projectname`, you can refer it to it as `polls.models.Poll`.